# Return unique arrays from a list of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays that looks like this:

```
 var lst = [
     ['abc', 'ab'],
     ['a'],
     ['abc', 'ab'],        // dup
     ['abc', 'ab', 'bc'],
     ['c', 'a', 'c'],
     ['abc', 'ab', 'bc'],  // dup
     ['a'],
     ['c', 'a', 'c']       // dup
  ]
```

How can I remove duplicate items from this array?

The output I'm looking for is:

```
var lst = [['abc', 'ab'], ['a'], ['abc', 'ab', 'bc'], ['c', 'a', 'c']]
```

Comment: Why is for example `['c', 'a', 'c']` removed once when `['abc', 'ab']` is not?

Comment: do you want remove duplicated arrays?

Comment: @RokoCBuljan You changed the question slightly when editing, I suspect you corrected an unintentional error but turtle may want to comment on whether the change was correct.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. It reads correctly. I want to remove duplicate arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's that easy:

```
var lst = [['abc', 'ab'], ['a'], ['abc', 'ab'], ['abc', 'ab', 'bc'], ['c', 'a', 'c'], ['abc', 'ab', 'bc'], ['a'], ['c', 'a', 'c']]
var newLst = [];
var newLstJ = [];
for(var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++){
    var json = JSON.stringify(lst[i]);
    if(newLstJ.indexOf(json) === -1) {
        newLst.push(lst[i]);
        newLstJ.push(json);
    }
}
lst = newLst;
```

Comment: Hm... would that _really_ work with arrays containing arrays?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes you were write. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Are you sure this works? It doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: @turtle Please look at this http://jsfiddle.net/wumm/v7X5M/

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't realize I needed to do the stringify step for the comparison.